# Refresh text in tkinter message box

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a Python code that has many steps. Every step I make is a print that says that I have finished this step. I am looking for a way to open a message window and every step that ends then the print will appear in the same window until the end. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    t = None

    def say_hi(self):
        self.t.message.insert(END, "hi there!! \n")

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.QUIT = Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "QUIT"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit

        self.QUIT.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.hi_there = Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Launch",
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.create_window

        self.hi_there.pack({"side": "left"})

    def create_window(self):
        if(self.t):
            self.say_hi()
        else:
            self.t = Toplevel(self)
            self.t.wm_title("Message Window")
            self.t.message = Text(self.t, height=20, width=30)
            self.t.message.pack()
            self.say_hi()

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

You have the main application which opens a TopLevel Window with a textarea on it.

From the function say_hi you can write directly on the textarea from the created message window.

I hope this is what you were looking for.